# Remove the default option from image option of woocommerce "choose an option"

Tags: php, wordpress

[image]I am wondering how I can remove the "Choose an option" when you select image for an option. Please see this page.

http://omegahookahc.com/product/hookah-flavors/

All the options have an image and I have no way to remove these. I tried removing them, but CSS but the images gets messy when I click on it.

Comment: Can you clarify? I'm assuming you just want a dropdown? vs the images for selecting an option?

Comment: Please see screenshot

Comment: I want the option with image swatch but "choose an option" is also coming as a swatch which is not making any sense here

Comment: One thing you could do is change the default option for WooCommerce. This is under WooCommerce > Settings > Products and change the ID for the Placeholder Image. While not ideal, without having access to the plugin that is adding this it is hard to give you a specific answer.

Comment: Thank you. I wasnt able to find the plugin neither, its a template I am using, but setting an id in placeholder image also did not work.

Comment: You will need to reach out to the theme authors then as it is a paid theme and ask them. Its most likely added into the theme directly vs a stand alone plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add the following css code to your themes css file.

```
.variations span.trx_addons_attrib_item.trx_addons_attrib_image.trx_addons_tooltip[data-tooltip="Choose an option"] { display: none; }
```

Then make sure to set the default values in your variation.

[image]

Comment: Thank you but this only set the pre-selected values, those empty image swatches are there, is there a way to remove them?

Comment: Please see screenshot and the text in red

Comment: @ali, please check the answer now for the update.

Comment: Bingo, It worked like a charm.thank you so much